# 'list' object has no attribute 'read' facing this error in pdf2image

Tags: python, image, pdf, processing

I Have this code

```
tex=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(pdf2image.convert_from_path(PDF_PATH)),lang='mar')
```

I want to do something like this

```
tex=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_path),lang='mar')
```

Code

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
#import cv
import os
import pdf2image
import time
#from pikepdf import Pdf,PdfImage,Name
#defpdftopil()
PDF_PATH=r'C:\Users\Downloads\ViewPDF (1)_one_page.pdf'
img=pdf2image.convert_from_path(PDF_PATH)
tex=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(pdf2image.convert_from_path(PDF_PATH)),lang='mar')
print(tex)
cv2.nameWindow("Input image")
cv2.imshow("input Image",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow("Test")
cv2.destroyWindow("Main")
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\System\p\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2882, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ocr.py", line 12, in <module>
    tex=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(pdf2image.convert_from_path(PDF_PATH)),lang='mar')
  File "D:\System\p\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2884, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: `pdf2image.convert_from_path` returns a `list` consisting of an image object for each page of the document. What is the desired behaviour, do you want to iterate over each image or only take the first one?

Comment: You still have some analysis work to do, before this is a viable question.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  In particular, track `fp` -- you apparently expect it to be a list, but your code assigns a list to it.  How did that discrepancy come about?

Comment: You are trying to do too many things in one line.  Break the error line in separate parts, and then you should be able to detect what is the exact command causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

The line,

```
    pdf2image.convert_from_path(PDF_PATH)
```

returns a list of images, one for each page. The pdf2image project description (https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/) states:

```
    images = convert_from_path('/home/belval/example.pdf')
```

where *images will be a list of PIL Image representing each page of the PDF document.*

**Solution**

The PIL function, Image.open(), expects an image, not a list. Therefore, you could do one of two things:

1. Loop over the list returned by the convert_from_path() method and pass each list item (read: each image), to pytesseract.image_to_string()
2. If you are certain that your pdf contains only one page, just access only the first index of the list returned by the convert_from_path() method